# Fortran: extracting columns and rows from a matrix and use them as one dimensional arrays for multiplications

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran, fortran90

Suppose I have matrices `A` and `B` both having sizes n x n . Now I want to treat each column of A as a column matrix `ColA(i)` [i=1,n] and each row of B matrix as a row matrix `RowB(j)` [j=1,n].

Now can I use `matmul` function to construct a new matrix called `C` whose elements are found by multiplying ColA and RowB for all possible i and j values? Something like

```
do i = 1, n
 do j= 1, n
    C(i,j) = matmul( ColA(i), RowB(j) ) 
 end do
end do
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I can see three possible answers to your question, but I'm not sure which one you mean...

- Dot-product of column `i` of `A` and row `j` of `B`, which would be equal to the matrix-matrix multiplication `B*A`:

```
C = matmul( B,A )
```

- Outer Product: `C=colA * rowB^T`, but then each combination `i,j` would lead to an individual matrix `C`.

```
C = matmul( A(:,i), B(j,:) )
```

- Element-wise multiplication, which means that `C_ij = A_ij * B_ij`. This is quite simple in Fortran:

```
C = A*B
```

Take your pick!

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make sense. `ColA(i)` is not a vector, it is a scalar, you cannot pass scalars to matrix multiplication. The same way, `C(i,j)` is not a matrix, it is a scalar. `C` is a matrix.

Or If you mean `ColA` to be vector of vectors, that is not possible in Fortran. `C` would have to be matrix of matrices then, also not possible. It could be possible with derived types, but you would have to code it yourself.

Comment: No, `ColA(i)` may not be a way to define a column vector in fortran, but it is indeed according to my intention. So let me rephrase, I just want to multiply each columns of `A` to each row of `B`. I think this matrix multiplication is legitimate and I was wondering if I can use `matmul` routine that. If yes, how? 
[ If I sound still unclear to you, please let me know.]

Comment: I still do see the exact mathematical meaning. What multiplication? There are more of them, inner (scalar, dot) product, cross product, outer (dyadic, tensor) product, wedge product or even Clifford product... Or the element-wise multiplication.

Comment: I wanted to mean simple matrix multiplication between a row-vector and a column vector, which can be inner product or outer product case-wise. I guess, @Alexander has provided sufficient options. An inner product between a row and a column could be thought as dot products between two columns and one can use dot_product function in fortran as he has mentioned already.